# How do I export my Terminal Colorscheme?

Tags: terminal, colors, konsole

Running Linux Mint 17.1 with KDE. I use Konsole/Bash as my terminal, and I configured a nice colorscheme. I would like to export this colorscheme so that I can use the exact same scheme on another machine.

How do I export my colorscheme/terminal appearance settings?

Comment: For GNOME `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml` file contains the information about you terminal preference. No idea about KDE

Comment: Also your Gnome instructions work for older Gnome releases only. Newer ones use dconf.

Comment: I thought for Gnome it was `gconf` for Gnome 2, `gsettings` and `dconf` for Gnome 3?

Comment: I'm running KDE, not Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it:
On Manjaro (probably on other distros as well) and KDE plasma 5, user defined color schemes are stored in `~/.local/share/konsole`.

System color themes however are stored in `/usr/share/konsole/`. They all end with the `.colorscheme` extension.

So just copy your scheme file to your new machine in `~/.local/share/konsole` directory and you'll be able to select it when you edit your konsole profile in:

```
Settings > Edit current Profile > Appearance > Color schemes & font
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used KDE, but it seems to me that configuration files are stored in either `~/.config` (on KDE5) or `~/.kde4` (on KDE4). So you will want to find Konsole's configuration within there, and archive the file somewhere.

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#Configuration